# Action.type undefined error in Redux Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, async-await, reducers

I'm not sure why I'm forced to do a check if `actions` exists in my reducer. Could it be because we are using `async await` in our actions / API methods?

### Reducer

```
export const partyReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    if (action) { // <-- should not need this
        switch (action.type) {
            case Actions.SET_ROLES: {
                const roles = formatRoles(action.roles);

                return {
                    ...state,
                    roles
                };
            }

            default:
                return state;
        }
    }
    return state;
};

export default partyReducer;
```

### Actions

```
import {getRoles} from '../shared/services/api';

export const Actions = {
    SET_ROLES: 'SET_ROLES'
};

export const fetchRoles = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await getRoles();
        const roles = response.data;

        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SET_ROLES,
            roles
        });
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: Actions.SET_ROLES,
            roles: []
        });
    }
};
```

### Component that dispatches the action:

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchRoles();
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

...

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchRoles: () => {
            dispatch(fetchRoles());
        }
    };
};
```

### The Store

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {reducer as formReducer} from 'redux-form';

// Reducers
import partyReducer from '../reducers/party-reducer';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    let reducer = combineReducers({
        form: formReducer,
        party: partyReducer
    });

    let enhancements = [applyMiddleware(thunk)];

    if (process.env.PROD_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) {
        enhancements.push(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
    }

    return createStore(reducer, initialState, compose(...enhancements));
}
```

### What I've tried

I noticed my mapDispatchToProps was written kinda strange so I fixed that, but I still get the error `actions is undefined` if I remove the `if statement` :'(

```
import {fetchRoles as fetchRolesAction} from '../../../actions/party-actions';

...

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchRoles: () => dispatch(fetchRolesAction())
});
```

Comment: Code looks ok to me. How are you registering the reducer in the root reducer? Also did you include the thunk middleware?

Comment: @Clarity just added the store code above

Comment: The code looks ok. Why the double export in the reducer though ?

Comment: Weird, the store code also ok. I would probably start debugging with thunk actions and check if/what kind of action it actually dispatches.

Comment: @Clarity ah it was the way the tests were written!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Was my test!

```
it('returns expected initState', () => {
    let expected = {roles: []};
    let actual = partyReducer();

    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
});
```

^ test above is suppose to see if the initial state is return if no state is passed in. However Actions should Always be passed in.

### Fix:

```
it('returns expected initState', () => {
     let expected = {roles: []};
     let actual = partyReducer(undefined, {}); // <-- undefined state, + action

     expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
});
```